# onSubmitEditing is called twice when keyboard is dismissed

Tags: android, react-native

I want to get current text from `TextInput` when keyboard is dismissed by pressing search button. In order to get the text, I use `onSubmitEditing` but it is called twice only if I set returnKeyType to 'search'. Here is a code snippet.

```
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1, justifyContent:'center'}}>
        <TextInput
          style={{alignSelf:'stretch'}}
          onChangeText={(searchInput) => this.setState({ searchInput }) }
          placeholder='Search'
          returnKeyType='search'
          onFocus={() => console.log('onFocus')}
          onBlur={() => console.log('onBlur')}
          onChange={(event) => console.log('onChange text: ' + event.nativeEvent.text)}
          onEndEditing={(event) => console.log('onEndEditing text: ' + event.nativeEvent.text)}
          onSubmitEditing={(event) => console.log('onSubmitEditing text: ' + event.nativeEvent.text)}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

It happens only in android(`onSubmitEditing` is called once in iOS). Also `onSubmitEditing` is called once when I use RN 0.24 but it is called twice in the latest version(0.30). Is this expected behavior? and is there a way to take the text once when keyboard is dismissed by pressing search button?

Comment: I am experiencing the same behaviour with react-native 0.30. Android API 22

Comment: Anyone who is interested in this issue could see current status in  [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10443)

Answer (score 1):

solve this issue by use textinput.blur

```
<TextInput
  ref={component => this._textInput = component}
  onSubmitEditing={this._onSubmitEditing.bind(this)}
  onEndEditing={this._onPressSearch.bind(this)}
  returnKeyType='search'
  style={styles.inputText}/>

  _onSubmitEditing(){
    this._textInput.blur();
  }
  _onPressSearch(event){
    console.log(event.nativeEvent.text);
  }
```